# Any alternatives to key word 'or' in an sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I probably didn't word the question right buy I have a query that is taking a substantial amount of time because of 'or'.

```
select stuff 
from table1 T1
left join table2 T2 on T2.field1 = T1.field or T2.field2 = T1.field
where some condition
```

I have to check both fields to join. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I assume T2.field1 and T2.field2 are strings?  Maybe some indices are in order?  Have you checked out the query plan in sql server management studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two options I can think of based on what's provided:

### Use IN instead

```
   select stuff 
     from table1 T1
left join table2 T2 on T1.field IN (T2.field1, T2.field2)
    where some condition
```

### Using a UNION

Mind that I used `UNION ALL`--it's faster than `UNION`, but `UNION` removes duplicates so alter to suit your needs:

```
   select stuff 
     from table1 T1
left join table2 T2 on T1.field = T2.field1
    where some condition
UNION ALL
   select stuff 
     from table1 T1
left join table2 T2 on T1.field = T2.field2
    where some condition
```

Comment: @Eric: Then you'll have to provide actual detail for us to diagnose the performance issue.

Comment: I used Union instead of Union all. Seems to give me the results i needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the rule either T2.field1 = T1.field true or  T2.field2 = T1.field.
when output depends on atleast one is true.

```
**select stuff 
from table1 T1, table2 T2 
where some condition AND (T2.field1 = T1.field or T2.field2 = T1.field)**
```

Comment: brackets do not improve performance; they only ensure order of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `T1.field IN (T2.field1, T2.field2)` but I doubt it will improve your query performance.